# Symfony Persisting oneToOne bidirectional relationship in a better way

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony

I have 2 entities

1. User
2. jobSeekerProfile

and they are setup in oneToOne bidirectional

`User.orm.yml`

```
oneToOne:
    jobSeekerProfile:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\JobSeekerProfile
        mappedBy: jobSeekerUser
        cascade:  ["persist"]
```

`JobSeekerProfile.orm.yml`

```
oneToOne:
    jobSeekerUser:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: jobSeekerProfile
```

**Scenario 1**

Now inside my controller I am trying to save my inverse side of the relationship, the data gets saved but not the relationship ID.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $user = $form->getData();
    // encode the password manually
    $encodedPassword = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $form->get('plainPassword')->getData());
    $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
        'success',
        $this->get('translator')->trans('success_registration')
    );
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));

}
```

**Scenario 2**

If I change my controller to as following the relationship id gets saved. but then 2 records are added to the table one with relationship id and one without.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $user = $form->getData();
    // encode the password manually

    $encodedPassword = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $form->get('plainPassword')->getData());
    $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $JS = new JobSeekerProfile();
    $JS->setFirstName($form->get('jobSeekerProfile')['firstName']->getData());
    $JS->setLastName($form->get('jobSeekerProfile')['lastName']->getData());
    $JS->setJobSeekerUser($user);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->persist($JS);
    $em->flush();
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
        'success',
        $this->get('translator')->trans('success_registration')
    );
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));

}
```

My question is, shouldn't the relationship id get saved as well using `scenario 1` because rest of the data is getting saved so whats stopping the relationship id to get saved as well?

My question 2 is, if suppose the answer to above question is no then is `scenario 2` the right approach, it does the job but is it the symfony way of doing things?

Comment: User::setJobSeekerProfile needs to call JobSeekerProfile::setUser

Comment: @Cerad thank you, can you please elaborate more as it is not clear to me what you are saying. New to Symfony and still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My physic abilities tell me that your user_id column in your job_seeker_profile table is null.  Is that correct?

If so then the most likely problem is that you are not setting the relation between User and JobSeekerProfile.

```
class User {
  public function setJobSeekerProfile($profile) {
    $this->jobSeekerProfile = $profile;
    $profile->setUser($this); // THIS is what you are missing
```

Comment: your physic abilities are amazing :)

Comment: Thanks.  This is actually an extremely common question.  It just happens to be one that is difficult to search for.

Comment: Thanks, I am just curious when we have already setup relationships via the yml or annotations then why do we need to add this? symfony already creates the linked column for us then why it does not full it up?

Comment: It's a tradeoff.  Doctrine 2 tries to focus on persistence and avoids messing with the entities themselves as much as possible.  Too much magic can be a bad thing.

Comment: Nice, I hope I will remember this. Thanks alot for the help